# Visual Studio does not suppress MVC1000 warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, code-analysis, editorconfig

One of our projects has a lot of issues that cause over thousand warnings right now. This leads to the problem that new warnings go unrecognized during development. Since we cannot solve all warnings through the whole code base right now, we decided to temporarily disable several types of warnings.

We added a `.editorconfig` file and tried to disable some warnings using `dotnet_diagnostic` rules:

```
[*.cs]
dotnet_diagnostic.CS0219.severity = none
dotnet_diagnostic.CS1998.severity = none
dotnet_diagnostic.CS4014.severity = none
dotnet_diagnostic.MVC1000.severity = none
```

This works exactly as intended for the first three rules, however the warnings with the code `MVC1000` still appear in the error list of Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.15). This is really strange, cause Visual Studio seems to read and understand the line in the `.editorconfig` file, as it can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Using the Visual Studio UI to change the severity also reflects in the `.editorconfig` file.

Does anyone have an idea why Visual Studio ignores this line, but not the other three lines? Is the reason for this somehow linked to the difference between rules defined by Visual Studio and rules defined by an analyzer? Is there any solution to this problem?

**Update:**

I noticed that some of the `CS0219` warnings still appear in the error list and that all of these warnings come from `.cshtml` files, which makes sense, since right now only `.cs` files are configured in the `.editorconfig` file and this causes all `MVC1000` rules to be shown. I now changed the file to appyly for `.cshtml` files, too, and now the warnings are not shown in the source files anymore, but they still appear in the error list:

```
[*.{cs,cshtml}]
dotnet_diagnostic.CS0219.severity = none
dotnet_diagnostic.CS1998.severity = none
dotnet_diagnostic.CS4014.severity = none
dotnet_diagnostic.MVC1000.severity = none
```

Comment: This comment may not adress the question, but if you have thousand of times the MVC1000 warning and "_Rendering a partial using IHtmlHelper.Partial or IHtmlHelper.RenderPartial extension methods results in blocking calls. This may result in performance degradation and application dead locks issues due to thread pool starvation._" you could consider not supressing it but fixing it because of the associated performance degradation.

Comment: @Cleptus You are completely right and we definitely want to fix those issues, but it will require some preparation and tests afterwards. Right now there are certain individual warnings that drown in the flood of warnings like MVC1000 which can and will be fixed all together at some later point.